# VB -Parentheses! Please explain?

Tags: vb.net

```
Sub Main() 

    Console.WriteLine("check")   
    Console.Read()

End Sub
```

Why does Sub Main ()  need them? How do they apply to this procedure?
.WriteLine("")  here i am adding a value.
Console.Read()  is this holding the value "check" to show on console? Why why are they here.
I know all you experts think this is a dumb question, however i can not wrap my head around it help! To me these are boxes that hold or pass a procedure value. 
Is sub main a container holding the code the uses enters? If so, why is it that when a form button is used it is full? But here a VB default unused and empty?  Seems to me with no event values it should not be there....?????

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your question; are you asking for the language designers' reasoning behind the syntax for declaring functions?

Comment: I am asking what is inside of the empty parentheses? Is there nothing and there just for show?

Comment: It indicates a certain kind of call, in this case a sub or a function, as opposed to a member property.  If it helps, you can think of them containing NULL, void, Nothing, etc, but to be nice to the programmers, the VB.Net team made it so programmers don't need to explicitly pass in the empty value.

Answer (score 8):

Parenthesis are required when they are required, and [optional](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/optional) when they are optional. In the case of empty parameter/argument lists parenthesis are "just for show".

A [Sub Procedure](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/831f9wka.aspx) can be declared as `Sub Main()` or `Sub Main` - the parenthesis are optional when there are no parameters. Likewise, procedures/functions can be invoked without parenthesis if (and only if) no arguments are supplied.

```vb
Sub A               ' ok, no parameter list - no need for parenthesis
Sub A()             ' it's fine to use parenthesis anyway
Sub B(x as Integer) ' need parenthesis for parameter list

obj.A               ' ok, no arguments - no need for parenthesis
obj.A()             ' it's fine to use parenthesis anyway
obj.B(42)           ' need parenthesis when arguments are specified
```

In the above, the definitions of `A` and invocations of `A` are equivalent as the parenthesis are optional in these cases.

Comment: So why are they if not needed? They are empty?

Comment: @user3371628 The parenthesis are [*optional*](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/optional), per the language rules, if there are no parameters/arguments. Programmers may either include (or omit) such optional parenthesis per stylistic preferences and both forms are semantically equivalent. (There is a difference in other languages, but in VB.NET both forms of declaring/using `A` are the same.)

Answer (score 3):

When calling a method you do have a choice in VB whether you want to include the parentheses if there are no parameters.  The same holds true for the definition of a method, be it a function or a sub.

See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dz1z94ha.aspx (Sub Statement on MSDN).

> Calling a Sub Procedure
>
> You call a Sub procedure by using the procedure name in a statement
>   and then following that name with its argument list in parentheses.
>   You can omit the parentheses only if you don't supply any arguments.
>   However, your code is more readable if you always include the
>   parentheses.

Comment: So your saying there is nothing in them? I can not wrap my head around that.

Comment: Yes, that is what @Abraham is saying. Visual Basic has it's own distinct set of syntax rules.  In VB you can call a sub with or without parenthesis.  It might not look right to you, but it is an option in the language.

Comment: @user3371628, VB makes it confusing because parentheses are optional and parentheses are also used for other purposes, such as arrays.  The () make it easier for people familiar with other languages to read VB.  That is one good reason to include them always.  Also, parentheses are a way to tell the difference between a property and a method.