# What is the difference between .Keys and .Keys() when looping through a Dictionary in VBA

Tags: excel, vba, dictionary, key

To loop though a Dictionary in VBA two options are:

```
For Each key in dc.Keys
Next key
```

and

```
For Each key in dc.Keys()
Next key
```

Is there a difference?

Comment: [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22467973/4717755) has the explanation you're looking for.

Comment: Yes, I think so

Comment: Hmm. Comment of @PeterT points to VB.Net. Obviously, the rules in VB.Net are slightly different (`Sub A` without parenthesis is not possible in VBA).

Comment: To add, the brackets denote function and the `Keys()` in dictionary is a function. VBA however, happily accepts `Keys` since there's no argument to be passed to the function.